# Tkinter - update variable constantly, without pressing the button

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

So here's my python script:

```
from Tkinter import *
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

#p = GPIO.PWM(12, 50)
#p.start(0)

def cmd():
   speed = "Rotor speed= " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = speed)
   #dc = int(var.get())
   #p.ChangeDutyCycle(dc)

tk = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(tk, from_=100, to=0, variable = var)
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)
button = Button(tk, text="Set speed", command=cmd)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)
label = Label(tk)
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()

print("Closing the program and cleaning up the GPIO")
#p.stop()
#GPIO.cleanup()
```

Some parts are commented out for now because I'm working on the code on my PC and not the Raspberry Pi. I left them for the context.

So This code creates a very simple GUI for my helicopter. It works just fine, but to change the duty cycle of my PWM pin (`cmd()` function) I have to press the button.

I tried to make my program check for the value of the slider automatically but I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas how could I change this code to change the value of `dc` along with the slider movement, without having to press the button to update it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by *change the value of dc along with the slider movement* please?

Comment: `dc` is the duty cycle on pin #12. With the current program, when I press the button, it changes `dc` to whatever the value of the slider is.

What I'm trying to do is to automatically poll the position of the slider without pressing the button, so the value of `dc` would match the value of slider all the time.

Comment: Basically right now I have to press the button every time I want to perform: 
`dc = int(var.get())` which works but it's not ideal. I'd rather have the value match the slider at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this: Since `Scale` also have a `command` argument (which is called every time the scale is modified), it also passes the value of `scale.get()` when calling. This way, you can get rid of your button.

```
from Tkinter import *
def cmd(speed):
    speed_text = "Rotor speed= " + str(speed)
    label.config(text = speed_text)
    # or you can change it like this(many people prefers this way more):
    # label['text'] = speed_text
    # dc = speed

tk = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(tk, from_=100, to=0, variable = var, command=cmd)
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)
label = Label(tk)
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added all the GPIO code and it worked exactly how I wanted it to.  

Thanks